# Webpack use UglifyJSPlugin to ONLY remove comments

Tags: webpack

I would like to use the Webpack UglifyJSPlugin to only remove comments from my bundle. I currently have the following UglifyJSPlugin configuration:

```
webpackPlugins = [
    new DedupePlugin(),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: false,
        minimize: false,
        outputs: {
            comments: false
        }
    })
]
```

However, this still seems to minify the entire bundle. Is there another option to remove comments I am not taking advantage of? Is there a way to do this properly with UglifyJSPlugin?

Answer (score 9):

This is what you need:

```
new UglifyJsPlugin({
    comments: false,
}),
```

Answer (score 4):

Using webpack 2, the settings below worked for me.

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  output: {
    comments: false,
    beautify: true,
  },
  mangle: false,
  compress: false,
}),
```

Comment: Yes, I added

```, optimization: {
    minimize: true, minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: false,
            beautify: true,
          },
          mangle: false,
        compress: false,
        } 
      })
    ] }```to the bottom of the webpack config js and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is probably "beautify" combined with "mangle".

"Beautify" will output indented code instead of a one-line file, so you want this to be `true`. "mangle" will make your code as short as possible (e.g. by abbreviating variable names), so you want this to be `false`.

For more info about these two options see the [UglifyJS README](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#usage)

```
webpackPlugins = [
    new DedupePlugin(),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
        beautify: true,
        mangle: false
    })
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack 5 now has a slightly different config file:

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                        beautify: true,
                    },
                    mangle: false,
                    compress: false
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
    ...
}
```

[UglifyjsWebpackPlugin Docs](https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/)